# Why MouseDown event handler is not getting hit?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have this very simple button in a WPF that is supposed to call a function `preview()` on *MouseDown*, and function `hide()` on  *MouseUp*. However it's not working and **not even hitting its event handler**. What is my mistake?

I tried changing the background property, no use. *MouseLeave* and *MouseClick* both work but that's not what I want.

XAML:

```
<Button x:Name="previewButton" Background="#FF383434" Margin="5,5,8,0" MouseDown="previewButton_MouseDown" MouseUp="previewButton_MouseUp" MouseLeave="previewButton_MouseLeave" TouchDown="previewButton_TouchDown" TouchUp="previewButton_TouchUp" TouchLeave="previewButton_TouchLeave" Grid.Row="1" Click="previewButton_Click" Padding="0" >
    <StackPanel Height="98" Width="49">
        <Image Source="/EZ3D;component/Resources/old/eye.png" Margin="0,17,0,0" />
        <TextBlock Text="Preview" TextWrapping="WrapWithOverflow" Margin="0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Padding="0" FontSize="13" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Button>
```

Code Behind

```
private void previewButton_TouchDown(object sender, TouchEventArgs e)
{
    ShowPreviewImage();
}

private void previewButton_TouchUp(object sender, TouchEventArgs e)
{
    HidePreviewImage();
}

private void previewButton_TouchLeave(object sender, TouchEventArgs e)
{
    HidePreviewImage();
}

private void previewButton_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    ShowPreviewImage();
}

private void previewButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ShowPreviewImage();
}

private void previewButton_MouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    HidePreviewImage();
}

private void previewButton_MouseLeave(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    HidePreviewImage();
}
```

Comment: Did you happen to try the PreviewMouseDown event?

Comment: @bob No I did not. What is that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Handle **PreviewMouseDown** instead of MouseDown event, PreviewMouseUp instead of MouseUp and so on. It should work for you.

```
<Button x:Name="previewButton" Background="#FF383434" Margin="5,5,8,0" PreviewMouseDown="previewButton_MouseDown" MouseDown="previewButton_MouseDown" PreviewMouseUp="" MouseUp="previewButton_MouseUp" MouseLeave="previewButton_MouseLeave" TouchDown="previewButton_TouchDown" TouchUp="previewButton_TouchUp" TouchLeave="previewButton_TouchLeave" Grid.Row="1" Click="previewButton_Click" Padding="0" >
            <StackPanel Height="98" Width="49">
                <Image x:Name="Image1" Source="/EZ3D;component/Resources/old/eye.png" Margin="0,17,0,0" />
                <TextBlock Text="Preview" TextWrapping="WrapWithOverflow" Margin="0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Padding="0" FontSize="13" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </Button>
```

All FrameworkElements expose these events. All 'Preview...' events are 'Tunnel' events while the other Mouse events are 'Bubble' events. The tunnel events are raised first on higher level elements, e.g. if you mouse over a button element, the first Preview mouse event goes to the Window and then on down through all of its descendants until it reached the ultimate target, in this case the button. Then the normal, i.e. non-preview' mouse event starts bubbling up from there until it reaches the Window. Anywhere along this chain an event handler can mark the event as handled and stop the process. Here the MouseDown bubbling event gets handled by your textblock placed inside the button.

Answer (score 0):

Certain controls handle input events internally, you usually can use the tunneling version of events (`Preview*`) in those cases. See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742806%28v=vs.100%29.aspx#routing_strategies).